# Java Encryption Conversion from .NET

Tags: java, encryption, md5, sha256

I was given this .NET code and I need to convert it to Java. I have found a bunch of articles but nothing I try works.

```cs
public string EncryptNVal(string vVal, string accountNumber, string sharedSecret)
{
    byte[] IV = Convert.FromBase64String(vVal);
    byte[] Key = Convert.FromBase64String(sharedSecret);
    SymmetricAlgorithm sa = Rijndael.Create();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, sa.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV),
       CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accountNumber);
            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            ms.Position = 0;
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

This is some of my attempt which you can guess throws exceptions.

```java
public String EncryptNVal(String vVal, String accountNumber, String sharedSecret) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
 
   byte[] IV = Base64.decodeBase64(vVal);
   byte[] Key =Base64.decodeBase64(sharedSecret);
   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   byte[] salt = new byte[16];
   random.nextBytes(salt);
   KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(sharedSecret).toString().toCharArray());
   SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
   SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
   PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(IV,salt,1000);
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
  
   byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(accountNumber.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   return Base64.encodeBase64String(ciphertext);
```

In the same project I have this code which I think I got correct, but any confirmation on that would be helpful as well.

.NET code I was given

```cs
 public string GetMd5Hash(string input)
        {
            using (var md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
                byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                // Loop through each byte of the hashed data
                // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
                foreach (var t in data)
                {
                    sBuilder.Append(t.ToString("x2"));
                }
                // Return the hexadecimal string.
                return sBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

What I wrote in Java:

```java
public String GetHash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   
   byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
   md.update(inputBytes);
   byte inputHash[] = md.digest();
   StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
   for (int i = 0; i < inputHash.length; i++) {
       hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & inputHash[i]));
   }
   return hexString.toString();
}
```

On a side note I can use either MD5 or SHA256, the .NET code was using MD5, so I was trying to follow that since my knowledge of encryption is about null. I am willing to use the SHA256 if someone can give me good advice.

Comment: Instead of the C# `GetHash()` method, you posted the C# `EncryptNVal()` method a second time.

Comment: Updated to have correct .NET code for the second part

Comment: The C# code simply applies AES in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding, i.e. you have to use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` in the Java code. Key and IV must be passed directly (after Base64 decoding) via `SecretKeySpec` and `IvParameterSpec` respectively. A key derivation (as in `PBEWithMD5AndDES`) is not involved in the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I took me some time, and a lot of errors to figure this out, but here's a java method which yields exactly the same output as your C# method.

I'm no expert at all in crypto stuff, but this seems to do the work.

```
public static String EncryptNVal(String vVal, String accountNumber, String sharedSecret){
   try {
      byte[] vValAsBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(vVal);
      byte[] sharedSecretAsBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(sharedSecret);
      byte[] accountNumberAsBytes = accountNumber.getBytes();

      SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(sharedSecretAsBytes, "AES");
      IvParameterSpec iv  = new IvParameterSpec(vValAsBytes);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
      byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(accountNumberAsBytes);
      String signature = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
      return signature;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "<dummy>";
   }
}

private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
   char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
   for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
         int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
         hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
         hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
   }
   return new String(hexChars);
}
```

A few additional info :

- Rijndael is **not** AES, in the sense that it's not implementing the actual AES standard. If this is for production use, I'd suggest moving to actual AES (take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes) for info).
- `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is the closest match I could find for C#'s [Rijndael](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndael?view=net-6.0) . Although C# seems to use `PKCS7`, this doesn't seem available for Java (at least not on my system). `PKCS5Padding` yields the same result, but it will probably not work in 100% of the cases.
- It only required trial and error, no deep knowledge of either C# or Java. You'll probably face similar challenges (or related problems which will be induced by your particular use case), and I'd suggest you apply a similar workflow as mine, when it comes to translating from a language to another :

  - Use and abuse of printing capabilities, to ensure all steps of both codes have the same state
  - Arrange the code with the same logical flow on both sides
  - **Thoroughly** read the documentation of your source function that you want to translate

Comment: Java does use PKCS7 padding when you specify `PKCS5` padding. The "PKCS5" is simply a historical holdover from the old days before 128-bit block ciphers were common.